# How to disable hybris soft login?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to disable hybris in-build soft login functionality.I have restarted the hybris server still able to see the customer as logged customer.
I tried with changging the some tomacat server properties like context.xml

```
 <Manager pathname="" />
```

Still its not working.

Comment: Which Hybris version you use ?

Comment: Hybris version 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Hybris Soft login is a feature of spring security.A soft logged in user can browse the application, but pages like account page and checkout pages are secured by hard login. To access these pages, he has to provide password again.

Comment the **security:remember-me** tag in the spring-security.xml file

```
<!-- <security:remember-me key="hybrisshopstorefront" services-ref="rememberMeServices"/> -->
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hybris in-build soft login functionality or remember-me tag functionality can be disabled using two ways, the first that I suggest :

**First :** Remove the remember-me configuration from spring security file `spring-security.xml` :

```
<security:remember-me key="myKey" token-validity-seconds="864000" />
```

**Seconde :** Remove the input checkbox from jsp (not recommended)

```
<input id="j_remember" name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="checkbox">
```